# I am getting this 403 Forbidden error on Sourcetree while trying to push to remote repository:

Tags: git, git-bash

I am trying to push the code that I have committed, to the remote repository. but when I give the command `$git push` in git-bash, I keep getting the following error. 
(Here, I push to 'https://bitbucket.org/Sam1/test_repository.git/')

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/Sam1/test_repository.git/': T
he requested URL returned error: 403
```

Can someone explain why this error occurs, and how to resolve it in order to push successfully?

Comment: That error typically occurs because the credentials you have used does not have permissions to push to the repository.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I saw that very same suggestion most of the posts. But I could solve the issue by this `git remote show origin` .